# Не работает корректно функция

Tags: javascript

Ссылка на [задание](https://learn.freecodecamp.org/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-algorithm-scripting/where-do-i-belong).

```js
function getIndexToIns(arr, num) {
  // Find my place in this sorted array.
  arr = arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  });

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr.length == 0) {
      console.log(0);
      return 0;
    } else if (arr[arr.length] >= num) {
      console.log(arr[i]);
      console.log(i);
      return i + 1;
    } else if (arr[i] >= num) {
      console.log(arr[i]);
      console.log(i);
      return i;
    }
  }
}

getIndexToIns([2, 5, 10], 15);
```

Не проходит проверки :

```
getIndexToIns([2, 5, 10], 15)should return 3

getIndexToIns([2, 5, 10], 15) should return a number.
getIndexToIns([], 1) should return 0

getIndexToIns([], 1)should return a number.
```

Comment: У вас ошибка в этой строке => `} else if (arr[arr.length] >= num) {`... Длина массива считается от 1 до N, а у вас i начинается с нуля, т.е. `arr[arr.length]` будет всегда undefined. Можно так сделать => `arr[arr.length-1]`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вот решение:

```js
function getIndexToIns(arr, num) {
  let index = arr.sort((a, b) => {
    return a - b;
  }).findIndex(x => Number(x) >= Number(num));
  return index < 0 ? arr.length : index;
}
```

и мой вариант допустимого изменения вашего кода:

```js
function getIndexToIns(arr, num) {
  // Find my place in this sorted array.
  arr = arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  });

  let a = 0;

  if (Number(arr[arr.length - 1]) < Number(num)) {
    a = arr.length;
  } else {

    for (let i = 0, max = arr.length; i < max; i++) {
      if (Number(arr[i]) >= Number(num)) {
        a = i;
        break;
      }
    }

  }

  return a;

}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо) не перестаю удивляться когда пишут однострочную функцию которая заменяет мою многострочную) не могли ли бы вы дать коментарий как исправить мою функцию?)

Comment: .findIndex(x => Number(x) >= Number(num)); а эта часть что делает ?Это вместо for ?

Comment: возвращает индекс элемента в массиве - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex